# ¿Cómo restringir la lista de valores de un ComboBox a los valores únicos de una columna?

Tags: vba

Quiero restringir la lista de valores de un ComboBox a los valores únicos de una columna.

Entonces intenté :

```
With ComboBoxFunction
    .List = Sheets("RECAP").Range("E2:E127").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique :=True
End With
```

Pero me devuelve que hay un `Error de compilación: esperado: final de expresión`

También intenté añadir a la mano con .AddItem:

```
With ComboBoxFunction
    .AddItem = "EQUIP"
    .AddItem = "COND"
    .AddItem = "CA"
End With
```

Pero me devolvía `Error de compilación: esperado: función o variable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con respecto al segundo error , podrias probar eliminando el "="? 
 Deberia quedar asi:

```
  With ComboBoxFunction
       .AddItem  "EQUIP"
       .AddItem  "COND"
       .AddItem  "CA"
   End With
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Quizá es algo más complicado, pero así funciona para añadir datos:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim arrLista As Variant
    Dim Item As Variant
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim C As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RECAP")
        Lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("E1:E" & Lrow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
        ReDim arrLista(1 To Application.CountA(.Range("E2:E" & Lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)))
        x = 1
        For Each C In .Range("E2:E" & Lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            arrLista(x) = C
            x = x + 1
        Next C
    End With

    For Each Item In arrLista
        With UserForm1.ComboBox1 'cambia esto por el nombre de tu formulario y combobox
            .AddItem Item
        End With
    Next Item

End Sub
```

Hay que utilizar loops para meter datos en los combobox, no vale con `.List`

Comment: Muchas gracias, actualicé mi pregunta agregando mi problema con AddItem.

Comment: Tiene que ser tema de la referencia al combobox, debes llamarlo haciendo referencia la nombre del formulario y el nombre del combobox. mi línea de `With UserForm1.Combobox1` así es como se llaman formulario y combobox. Edita eso para que sean los tuyos y debería funcionar.

Comment: Ja, agregué con el nombre de mi formulario de usuario pero no funcionó. Sin embargo, antes, cuando no lo puse y dejé solo un `MsgBox` en lugar de `AddItem`, se mostró un mensaje.

Comment: Pues he hecho un test y me ha devuelto el combobox con los items agregados... Dónde te resalta el error? Qué línea?